# Set pad between arrow and text in annotate function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

How do I set the distance (padding) between the arrow and the text in matplotlib's annotate function? Sometimes the text ends up being too close to the arrow and I would like to move them a little further apart.

Basic example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.annotate('Here it is!',xy=(-1,-1),xytext=(0,0),
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',lw=1.5))

plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.ylim(-10,10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For fancy arrows you can play with the `bbox` properties:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(7, 3))
pad_val = [-5, 0, 5]
for a,p in zip(ax, pad_val):
    a.annotate('Here it is!\npad={}'.format(p),xy=(-1,-1),xytext=(1,1),
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>', fc="k", ec="k", lw=1.5),
                bbox=dict(pad=p, facecolor="none", edgecolor="none"))
    a.set_xlim(-10,10)
    a.set_ylim(-10,10)
```

[image: set pad between arrow and text in matplotlib annotate]

Here the drawback is that you can't add a color behind the annotation (`facecolor="none"` is mandatory), or the arrow will always stick to the border of the frame and it might be ugly.

HTH

Comment: This seems to work great! (Not sure why you got downvoted...). For those who don't want to actually see the bounding box, you can pass `facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'` in the bbox dict. I changed this to the accepted answer, since it works with the example code that I originally posted, which uses the FancyArrow.

Comment: @DanHickstein Good point for the `'none'`, the `fc=None` did not work. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

To have full control of the distance, you must combine [jrjc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297428/jrjc) and [Ffisegydd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3005188/ffisegydd) answers.

The `pad` property of the Bbox defines the distance between the text and its containing box. The `shrink` property of the arrow is the distance between the arrow extremity and the box, not the text itself.

Also, to use `shrink` with `FancyArrowPatch` you must defined it separately: `shrinkA` for the origin (extremity of the arrow close to the text) and `shrinkB` for the destination.
From a [demo in Matplotlib's website](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/userdemo/connectionstyle_demo.html):

```
 ax.annotate("",
             xy=(x1, y1), xycoords='data',
             xytext=(x2, y2), textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="0.5",
                             shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                             patchA=None, patchB=None,
                             connectionstyle=connectionstyle,
                             ),
             )
```

So the full answer is both:

```
plt.annotate('Example text',
             xy=(-1,-1), xytext=(0,0),
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', shrinkA=0.15),
             bbox=dict(pad=0),
    )
```

Examples:

[image: Influence of Bbox pad and arrow shrink parameters on distance of arrow to text]

Comment: This is actually the clearest explanation IMHO! Now, is there any way to control where the arrow connects with the box? It is not at the xytext coordinates, but seems to be at the center of the bbox. If it is too much for here, I can start a new question.

Comment: I just did: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75484393/2606407

Comment: Just answered your question, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`shrink`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/annotations_intro.html) keyword argument in your `arrowprops` dictionary, but unfortunately the `FancyArrowPatch` object doesn't support it, so you'd have to remove the `arrowstyle='->'`.

The value given with `shrink` is a percentage that the tip/base will move away from the `xy` and `xytext` coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.annotate('Here it is!',xy=(-1,-1),xytext=(0,0),
             arrowprops=dict(lw=1.5, shrink=0.15))

plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.ylim(-10,10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! But no work-around for the fancy arrow? I much prefer the '->' style of arrow.

Comment: I don't believe so. You get an `AttributeError: 'FancyArrowPatch' object has no attribute 'set_shrink'` unfortunately.

Comment: @DanHickstein See my answer for a work around for the fancy arrows