# How to remove the whitespace between the tip of the arrow of a FancyArrowPatch and the target points?

Tags: matplotlib

When doing an image which puts lots of focus on some arrows, I noticed that the arrows didn't reach the full length between the specified points.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(5, 5)

w = 0.001
h = 1000

ax.set_xlim(0, w)
ax.set_ylim(0, h)

ax.add_artist(mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch(
    (w*1/3, h*0.0),
    (w*1/3, h*1.0),
    edgecolor='black',
    facecolor='red',
    arrowstyle=mpl.patches.ArrowStyle.CurveFilledAB(head_length=10, head_width=10)
))
ax.add_artist(mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch(
    (w*2/3, h*0.0),
    (w*2/3, h*1.0),
    edgecolor='black',
    facecolor='red',
    arrowstyle=mpl.patches.ArrowStyle.Simple(head_length=10, head_width=10, tail_width=1)
))
plt.savefig(
    'main.svg',
    format='svg',
    bbox_inches='tight',
    dpi=100,
)
```

produces:

[image]

and here is a screenshot of a browser zoom of the arrows showing that they don't touch the black line above:

[image]

How to make them touch exactly without that white space?

Tested on matplotlib==3.2.2.

Related questions:

- [Alter the width of an annotate arrow in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502594/alter-the-width-of-an-annotate-arrow-in-matplotlib)
- [Matplotlib - set pad between arrow and text in annotate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344891/matplotlib-set-pad-between-arrow-and-text-in-annotate-function)

Answer (score 4):

**`shrinkA=0` and `shrinkB=0`**

This is the first main direct reason why arrows don't touch.

Those values default to `2`, presumably because arrows were originally mostly used in annotations where some space is desired.

If I set them to zero:

```
FancyArrowPatch(
    shrinkA=0,
    shrinkB=0,
```

then the arrows touch as shown at:

[image]

A is for the start, and B is for the end of the arrow.

**The effect of `linewidth`**

Another thing to keep in mind however is that the `linewidth` can also affect if the arrow touches something or not.

For example, if I add an exaggerated `linewidth=10` to the original code:

```
FancyArrowPatch(
    shrinkA=0,
    shrinkB=0,
    linewidth=10,
```

then the result is:

[image]

so we note how:

- the tracing of the edges is always rounded, and therefore the arrows stop being pointy and become rounded with large line widths
- `Simple` and `CurveFilledAB` have different drawing algorithms: the one for `Simple` makes the arrow overrun the target, and `CurveFilledAB` makes it under run
- the linewidth above was so fat that it hid the red inner color

For the case of `Simple`, if you don't need a different border color, you can get back the pointy arrow with `linewidth=0`, and control the main arrow line width with `tail_width`.

This does not work for `CurveFilledAB` however: the drawing algorithm for that style is to use the border alone for the main arrow line, so I'm not sure how to separately control the main line width of a double headed arrow without getting the rounded corners, except for drawing two simple arrows which is uglier: [matplotlib simple and two head arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761717/matplotlib-simple-and-two-head-arrows) Seems like something that could be patched by adding a new `SimpleAB` class.

The result of:

```
FancyArrowPatch(
    shrinkA=0,
    shrinkB=0,
    linewidth=0,
```

is:

[image]